# How .NET Core, Mono and ASP.NET are related on a non Windows platform?

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core, dnx50

This breaks down to some trivial sub-questions

- Is .NET Core a Mono alternative?
- Will ASP.NET 5.0 run with .NET Core or with Mono in an OSX/Ubuntu environment?

I am confused, becasue I started at the .NET Core site, followed links toward ASP.NET 5 RC that all the way mentions Mono.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is .NET Core a Mono alternative?

Yes, in the sense that .NET Core is also a cross platform framework. The difference is that Mono is an implementation of the full .NET framework, while .NET Core is only a subset of the full .NET framework (and their code diverges), and framework packages are obtained via NuGet.

> Will ASP.NET 5.0 run with .NET Core or with Mono in an OSX/Ubuntu environment?

I can't speak for Mono, but ASP.NET 5 (which is [soon to be renamed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx) ASP.NET Core) will run on .NET Core on OS X (for development) and Ubuntu (for production or development) as well as Windows. ASP.NET 5 will also run on the full .NET Framework 4.6 on Windows.